# Ansible oc module inline definition

Tags: ansible, openshift

I am trying to deploy into openshift with inline file definition, But getting error as 
ERROR:

"msg": "parameters are mutually exclusive: ['name', 'definition']"

````
  oc:
    host: "{{openshift_uri}}"
    validate_certs: false
    name: "{{namespace}}"
    state: present
    definition: "{{ lookup('file', 'prometheus/dc.yaml') | from_yaml}}"
    token: "{{ openshift_devops_token }}"
  tags: deploy,deploy-prometheus```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the definition argument is also an alias for 'def' or 'inline'.

In the documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/oc_module.html), it states this about the inline argument:

> The inline definition of the resource. This is mutually exclusive
>   with name, namespace and kind.

So its one or the other, not both. However, this module is also going to be deprecated in 2.9, so you might want to switch over to the openshift_raw module instead, which is the updated version that might give you more options with what you are trying to do.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/openshift_raw_module.html